# Spring Blocking HTTP Interface Performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Since Spring's HTTP Interface only supports WebClient I have a question: is it ok to use it in a synchronous way?

Generally speaking, blocking calls it's not the best way to work with WebClient because it has a smaller thread pool(counting on non-blocking calls). There is a way to "tune" WebClient using Schedulers(like described [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/08/13/reactive-java)) but it's really not the best way to do it.

so, is it OK to use Spring HTTP Interface in a blocking manner performance-wise? Does Spring avoid performance pitfalls automatically?